# Intercept array creation routines with custom ndarray subclass

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a custom subclass of numpy ndarray and I want all array creation functions like `np.arange`, `np.zeros` and so on to be intercepted by my custom subclass for adding an attribute to it.

I see in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for `np.arange` the `like` keyword:

> Reference object to allow the creation of arrays which are not NumPy arrays. If an array-like passed in as like supports the **array_function** protocol, the result will be defined by it. In this case, it ensures the creation of an array object compatible with that passed in via this argument.

The problem is that I do not have a reference object (only the class) since the array is not yet created when calling the `np.arange` function. I thought something like this might work at first:

```
class Subclass(np.ndarray): 

    def __array_function__(self, func, *args):
        ... intercept func (np.arange) ...

np.arange(10, like=Subclass)
```

But this does not work. How can I intercept array creation routines with my custom class?

Comment: As a matter of terminology, `np.arange` and `np.zeros` are functions, not methods.  This `like` parameter might add some customization options as you want, but it's a new feature, and not wide spread.

Comment: Yes, reading the [NEP](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0035-array-creation-dispatch-with-array-function.html#usage-and-impact) it looks like ```np.arange(10, like=np.ndarray)``` should work. But it does not.

Comment: `np.arange(3,like=np.ndarray([]))` runs

Comment: Yes, Doing ```np.arange(10, like=Subclass(0))``` will intercept the function. But do I need to instantiate the class?

Comment: Well if I try `ndarray` is gives an error, while if I give an actual array it runs.  I don't have an alternate class to test this on.